# “Non-rhotic” is to R-droppers as “non-?????” is to L-droppers

Tags: single-word-requests, pronunciation, rhoticity

Certain speakers of English have a tendency to “drop” L’s that occur after a vowel but before another consonant, as in **balm, calm, golf, gulf, palm, wolf**, and many more.

Often these aren’t completely dropped, but instead change the preceding vowel a little bit. So instead of *wolf*, they have *woof*; instead of *palm* they have *pom* or *pawm*; instead of *golf*, they have *gawf*.

People who drop their R’s in a similar position are said to have a ***non-rhotic*** pronunciation there, or to speak a non-rhotic dialect.  What then is the corresponding term for someone who routinely drops their L’s, so **“a non-*?????* speaker”**?  *Lambdacism* and *lallation* seem like dead ends.

This isn’t a new thing either, considering the historical L’s no longer heard in words like *could* and *stalk*.  Whether it’s growing, I’m not sure, but perhaps so.

Comment: This is strange. I haven't heard of the l being changed in golf, gulf, palm and wolf. As for "people who drop their R's", I haven't heard of that, either. That might be the case with certain accents outside the UK but, not in it. Here in the UK, it is still pronounced, just in a nuanced way.

Comment: @Tristan There is a distinct regional and dialectal difference about the pronunciation of *bear*, for example, where some speakers in the UK will put a definite R on the end, almost as if they are to say *bearing*.

Comment: Yes, that's a kind of exaggerated r sound. Anyway, that's not quite the same thing as the point in the question. Nobody here really "drops" the letter r, as tchrist seems to think. They just pronounce it in a nuanced way. It is then pronounced in a soft, gentle way.

Comment: @Tristan I'm confused, are you positing that there's no such thing as a non-rhotic accent? Would your IPA transcription of a typical RP speaker saying the word "card", for example, include an /r/ (where I think a long vowel would normally go)? It is my understanding that this phenomenon is well recognized and understood by linguists.

Comment: Cameron: I'm saying that in the UK at least, the r is not actually "dropped". It's nuanced. Subtle. I realise that this can be difficult for people with very strong, rhotic accents to understand. Especially people with harsh, rhotic accents like American accents. I don't know IPA, so can't comment on it.

Comment: @Tristan please look at [these charts](http://www.soundcomparisons.com/). As you see, ***many*** UK speakers drop their R’s in words like [yard](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/research/gsound/Eng/Database/Phonetics/Englishes/ByWord/Word_108_yard.htm), [storm](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/research/gsound/Eng/Database/Phonetics/Englishes/ByWord/Word_088_storm.htm), [mother](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/research/gsound/Eng/Database/Phonetics/Englishes/ByWord/Word_056_mother.htm), [north](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/research/gsound/Eng/Database/Phonetics/Englishes/ByWord/Word_066_north.htm). Which of those are you?

Comment: @Tristan [Earth](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/research/gsound/Eng/Database/Phonetics/Englishes/ByWord/Word_017_earth.htm) is a very good example of non-rhotic speakers from the UK dropping their R’s. Also look at *better*, *daughter*, *bother*.  You could be mistaken because you are imagining an R phoneme there that underlies your pronunciation, so you just imagine you are producing something when you are not.

Comment: I had a look at and listened to, those links, tchrist. Useful. It seems to me, that this question raises the issue of what exactly, is meant by "dropping" the letter r. It seems that people with very strong, rhotic accents perceive that it is "dropped" in non-rhotic accents. If you familiarise yourself with these, you will realise that this is not exactly, the case.

Comment: As a speaker of the English kind of English, I can tell you that non-rhotic Rs are still pronounced. Just in a nuanced way. If they were not, that would change the pronunciation of words that contain it. Change them to pronunciations that are not used. For a more detailed explanation of this, see my answer here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10624/i-park-my-car-in-the-yard/73409#73409

Comment: @Tristan A “non-rhotic R” is an oxymoron: it is or it isn’t. It may be that your regional dialect is rhotic. It may also be that you are misperceiving, since all literature is unanimous in its agreement that non-rhotic dialects suppress Rs in particular situations and express them in others. You have a great deal of professional literature in stark disagreement with you. Let us ask Barrie on the morrow, as he is from the south o England and has the linguistic background to address your concerns. Are you perchance from the westcountry, or from the north? That could explain your confusion.

Comment: tchrist: Did you see my explanation in my answer at: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10624/i-park-my-car-in-the-yard/73409#73409 ? It seems to me, that would be a suitable place to discuss this and would help you understand what I mean.

Comment: What's more, English is not the only language where this has occurred. The Polish character **ɫ** was once pronounced like a dark l, but is now pronounced as [w].

Comment: @MarkBeadles It happens in Braziu, too.

Comment: I have never heard anyone pronounce "stalk" without the "l". It seems that for "golf", "gulf" and similar words, the "l" gets softened a bit by many speakers. It does seem to me though that maybe some of the non-rhotic speakers I have heard also soften that "l" more than others, or drop it completely. ("Calm down and get in the car" might sound like "Cahm down and get in the cah.")

Comment: @TecBrat Do you actually say *stalk* identically to how you say *stall* but add a *k* to the end?  Really?

Comment: @tchrist, yes but I did consider a title I have heard of, "Silk Stalkings", that shows there is a similarity in speech between "stalking" and "stocking".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It would appear that the word you’re looking for is *L-vocalization*, which, to quote [the wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-vocalization) page on the topic, “is a process by which an `[l]` sound is replaced by a vowel or semivowel sound”, which appears to be what is being described here, specifically with regards to English L-vocalization — where “an `/l/` sound occurring at the end of a word or before a consonant is replaced with the semivowel `[w]`”, such as the *palm/pawm* issue (the example given in the article is of *milk* `[mIwk]`).

I don’t think there is a term for someone who does this in the *non-??? speaker* fashion, although *L-vocalizer* could be a valid construction.

Comment: Oh, I answered: "There is a Wikipedia article that refers to this as L-dropping, which is distinct from L-breaking and L-deletion. I suppose you could call it "non-lambdal" but that doesn't appear to be in common usage." But you have covered the other part of the Wiki article I linked to, and yours fits better, so I'm deleting mine.

Comment: I’m going to accept that I can’t say *non-???*, and just use *L-vocalizer*.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

An alternative to LissyNumber's answer is "[velarisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velarization)" associated with a "[dark L](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velarized_alveolar_lateral_approximant)". I supposed you could call this *a velarising speaker*.

Comment: L-velarization ≠ l-vocalization.